# Strange MTproII behaviour

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

The following snippet

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{mtpro2}

\begin{document}

This one seems to be okay: $\footnotesize{\sim}$.
Let's see this: {\footnotesize $\sim$}.

\end{document}
```

produces a warning message:

```
 LaTeX Font Warning: Command \footnotesize invalid in math mode on input line 6.
```

and output in line with what one would expect. When uncommenting the line for the [MTProII](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package by Walter Schmidt, the Warning message disappears and the second occurrence of the \sim is mangled up, which seems very odd.

[image: mangled up \sim sign]

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: If the user manual does not explain it, you should IMHO ask the maintainer of that commercial font, why it behaves different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with an older version of the support files for these fonts

```
mtpro2.sty    2006/02/09 v0.97beta MathTimePro II
```

still distributed by PCTeX with the full and paid version of the fonts.

The way to correct it, is (before or after) installing the fonts grab a more updated copy of `mtpro2.sty` from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) here. It till be at least

```
mtpro2 2009/4/27 v2.3 MathTimePro II
```

and this and some other issues have been addressed.